# Файл с именем ... уже существует при создании шаблонного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Я работаю с C# WPF, пытался экспортировать шаблон окна. Создал окно, изменил в нем все, что надо, экспортировал. При добавлении элемента этого шаблона появляется ошибка (в названии вопроса и на скрине). Подозреваю, что прикрепленный к xaml-файлу xaml.cs-файл он пытается создать как такой же .xaml файл, а т. к. он уже существует, появляется ошибка. Файла с кодом cs нет. Как правильно экспортировать такой шаблон?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну очевидно, что у вас в папке проекта уже есть такой файл, его надо переименовать, либо удалить. Также непонятно как и что вы там "экспортируете", но обычно, при создании файлов, вас просят указать имя файла.

Comment: У меня изначально нет такого файла. При экспорте все названия файлов заменяются на переменные, и когда я создаю элемент из шаблона, имя уже другое. И сколько бы я разных имен не задавал, ошибка есть

Comment: "нету файла" - как смотрите, в студии? Если да, то студия это "проект", а в проекте файла может не быть, но на диске (в папке проекта) этот файл может находиться, поэтому будьте внимательней.

Comment: На диске его также нет. Это еще одно подтверждение тому, что студия вместо создания .xaml и .cs файлов пытается создать два xaml файла и соответственно вылетает с ошибкой

Comment: Ну, тогда в текущем виде, на данный вопрос невозможно дать ответ, ибо 1. Неизвестно  что вы там ставите и как. 2. Такая ошибка может произойти от кучи всяких проблем, от 
вашей невнимательности и до битого шаблона. Так что, советую дать больше данных.

Comment: Закрыть студию, удалить папки bin и obj, открыть студию.